# SQL - select max value of only rows from join tables

Tags: sql, join, max

I want to get the max value from `koderpm` column of `rincianpembayaran` table and `rpembayaran_tmp`. Is join be a solution for it?

I've tried this but it's not work

```
Select max(a.koderpem) 
from rincianpembayaran as a 
inner join rpembayaran_tmp as b on a.koderpem = b.koderpem
```

Comment: Could you give sample data, the output of the query you tried, and an explanation of why you believe it is not correct?

Comment: I have 3 doors, one should be white, but it's not. Why isn't it white? Don't neglect the most vital part of your question - the data. You expect people to spend their time helping you, then you need to spend the time to form your question.

Comment: i have data=R0003 on X column on XX table and i have data=R0004 on Y column on YY table. I want to get the max, it's R0004 value. But it was answered below. Thankyou so much @Phylyp

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maximum Value *Common* to Both Tables**

If you want the maximum `koderpem` value common to both tables, then your query would be correct.

e.g. If `rincianpembayaran` has `koderpem` values of 3, 4, 5 and `rpembayaran_tmp` has values 3, 4; then your query will return 4, since that is the largest value common to both tables.

**Maximum Value *Across* Both Tables**

However, if you want the maximum `koderpem` value across both tables, then you can use:

```
SELECT MAX(max_koderpem) FROM ( 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rincianpembayaran 
  UNION 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rpembayaran_tmp 
) AS x
```

e.g. Using the same example where `rincianpembayaran` has `koderpem` values of 3, 4, 5 and `rpembayaran_tmp` has values 3, 4; the above query will return 5.

**Explanation of Query**

There are two separate queries which return the maximum value of `koderpem` for each individual table. Then the outer query picks the largest among these values.

```
-- Explanation of how the query works: 

-- 1. This query gets the maximum value among 3, 4, 5 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rincianpembayaran -- returns 5 

-- 2. This query gets the maximum value among 3, 4 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rpembayaran_tmp   -- returns 4 

-- 3. This query merges both the above answers, to get 5, 4 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rincianpembayaran 
  UNION 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rpembayaran_tmp   -- returns 5, 4 

-- 4. This query picks the maximum among the 2 values 5, 4; thereby returning 5. 
SELECT MAX(max_koderpem) FROM ( 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rincianpembayaran 
  UNION 
  SELECT MAX(koderpem) AS max_koderpem FROM rpembayaran_tmp 
) AS x
```

Comment: It's all i mean :) @Phylyp